# weather or the weather in this context

Tags: articles

> 1, Nonliving things in the surrounding environment can cause population
> changes, such as **weather** or sunlight. (My lame paraphrase from a source which is provided in my own comment)
>
> 2, The remains of animals decompose and are quickly destroyed by **the
> weather** or eaten by some other creature. (from another source)

To my understanding, **the weather** can refer to specific types of weather like long periods of drought or heavy rain.

I guess both sentences refer to specific types of weather, so in both cases "the weather" can be used. But maybe in both cases it is also appropriate to eliminate the article.

Comment: Context 1: 
Populations of living beings are constantly changing. The number of humans, animals, insects, or plants living in a given area can vary because of two kinds of factors: biotic and abiotic. Biotic factors are living factors that can influence the size of populations, such as predators or other species competing for food. **Abiotic factors are nonliving things in the surrounding environment that can cause population changes, such as weather or sunlight.** Biotic and abiotic factors cause continual changes in the number of individuals that make up a population of organisms.

Comment: I provided Context 1 after the two perceptive answers of Astralbee and PPH who also shed light on other issues.

Comment: Context 2: The remains of plants and animals that lived on land are much more rarely preserved, for there is seldom anything to cover them over. When you think of the innumerable birds that one sees flying about, not to mention the equally numerous small animals like field mice and voles which you do not see, it is very rarely that one comes across a dead body. **They decompose and are quickly destroyed by the weather or eaten by some other creature.**

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to describe weather or sunlight as nonliving things. And these phenomena are not in the "surrounding environment" either.

Comment: Also, they decompose and are quickly destroyed are not parallel.

Comment: @Lambie wow, I am surprised that so many improvements could have been made. Context 1 appears in the TOEFL test, and Context 2 is from the article "The past life of the earth" by ERROL WHITE  from Discovery. I really respected these two sources.

Comment: THIS: Abiotic factors are nonliving things in the surrounding environment that can cause population changes, such as weather or sunlight. is fine. It was the one in the question that wasn't. You don't need "the" weather but it would not be wrong.

Comment: Both these are correct: Weather is a natural phenomenon. The weather is a natural phenomenon. Bear in mind, nouns like weather don't necessarily require a "the".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with simply 'weather' in the context you're describing.

As with most uses of the definite article "*the* weather" refers to something *specific*. It is usually the *current* weather, the weather on any given day, or the weather in a specific area you are already referring to.

You're speaking about all weather - perhaps not every kind of weather condition, but the ongoing effects of it over time. There is no limit to that, so the use of the definite article seems incorrect.

Just one side note - you speak about "weather *or* sunlight". Does 'weather' not encompass sunlight? "Nonliving things", while perfectly grammatical sounds a bit unusual. You could just say "*environmental conditions* can also cause population changes".

Comment: Do you still think article should not be used in sentence 2 after I provided context 2?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Astralbee that "nonliving things", though correct, sounds unusual. I would go with "**environmental factors**".

In addition, I think the first sentence is badly constructed and would suggest the following rewrite. .

Starting with:
**Environmental factors, such as...**

And ending in:
**can cause changes in the population.**
**can lead to population change.**

I also agree with @Astralbee's take on *weather* versus *the weather* and his astute observation that weather comprises sunlight.

Taking that in mind:

*Environmental factors, **such as weather**, can cause changes in the population.*

*Environmental factors, **such as precipitation, wind and/or sunlight**, can cause changes in the population.*

Comment: Do you still think article should not be used in sentence 2 after I provided context 2?